# RecyclerView scrollbar won't touch the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-recyclerview

**The problem:**

[image]

The *RecyclerView* is **fully** scrolled down yet the scrollbar will not touch the bottom of the screen

---

This is specific to a ***RecyclerView*** it **does not** occur with a ListView

Following similar questions on Stack Overflow I've already tried:

- Adding a small bottom padding/margin to the RecyclerView
- Adding a fake View at the end
- Removing margin/padding from every item

After spending enough time on this I have created a small verifiable example. I'm looking for how to make it act normally and touch the bottom when the view is fully scrolled down.

---

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="com.package.scrollerexample.MainActivityFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="130dp"
              android:background="#05EEFF">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="txt"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/txt2"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/recyclerList"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**RecyclerAdapterBasic**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerAdapterBasic extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterBasic.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Dummy> mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAll(List<Dummy> data){
        mDataSet.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Dummy i = mDataSet.get(position);
        holder.txt2.setText(i.getFieldA());
        holder.txt1.setText(i.getFieldB());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt1;
        public TextView txt2;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txt1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            txt2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        }
    }
}
```

**Dummy**

```
public class Dummy {
    public Dummy() {
    }

    public static String getFieldA(){
        return "12";
    }

    public static String getFieldB(){
        return "Field";
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

**MainActivityFragment**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        RecyclerAdapterBasic adapterBasic = new RecyclerAdapterBasic();
        List<Dummy> list = new ArrayList<Dummy>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++){
            list.add(new Dummy());
        }
        adapterBasic.addAll(list);
        layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterBasic);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an actual bug after all as mentioned in [Issue 78545](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78545) and can be fixed by switching to version **21.0.2**

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2'
```